# I need the if you Are you a Member? checked then they must be from Ontario only to validate in my for. How would I go about doing that.

Tags: javascript, html

Here's my code for the menu and function to check, it not working, Im not sure if I should be using the "9" beside Ontario in the drop down for it. If you need any other code from the program let me know

Here's my drop down menu code

```
document.getElementById('selProv').options.length = 0;
document.getElementById('selProv').options[0] = new Option("Alberta", 1);
document.getElementById('selProv').options[1] = new Option("British Columbia", 2);
document.getElementById('selProv').options[2] = new Option("Manitoba", 3);
document.getElementById('selProv').options[3] = new Option("New Brunswick", 4);
document.getElementById('selProv').options[4] = new Option("Newfoundland & Labrador", 5);
document.getElementById('selProv').options[5] = new Option("Northwest Territories", 6);
document.getElementById('selProv').options[6] = new Option("Nova Scotia", 7);
document.getElementById('selProv').options[7] = new Option("Nunavut", 8);
document.getElementById('selProv').options[8] = new Option("Ontario", 9);
document.getElementById('selProv').options[9] = new Option("Prince Edward Island", 10);
document.getElementById('selProv').options[10] = new Option("Quebec", 11);
document.getElementById('selProv').options[11] = new Option("Saskatchewan", 12);
document.getElementById('selProv').options[12] = new Option("Yukon", 13);
```

and my function to check

```
function chkIfMember() {
if (document.getElementById('chkMember').checked) {
    document.getElementById('selProv"').value === 'Ontario';
    return true;
}
else {
    alert('You must be from Ontario to be a member')
    document.getElementById('chkMbr').style.background = "#ff0000";
    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: Here's my checkbox code form HTML: 
     <p class="isMember">Are you a Member?</p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="chkMember" id="chkMember" 
    onclick="chkIfMember();" />

Comment: Also in the title should say Form

Comment: Then [edit] your question and correct that. Don’t fill comments with unformatted code.

Comment: `document.getElementById('selProv"')` should be `document.getElementById("selProv")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ( document.getElementById('chkMember').checked) {
    var menu= document.getElementById('selProv');
    if( menu.options[menu.selectedIndex].innerText=="Ontario") {
       //your codes when the condition is fulfilled
    }else {
       //otherwise
    }
}
```

Comment: my background color isint changing though:  else {
            alert('You must be from Ontario to be a member');
            document.getElementById('chkMember').style.background = "#ff0000";
        }

Comment: @JustStarting You can’t change the background color of a checkbox.

Comment: Is there a way to make so if it did fail validation, it would turn red

Comment: i just notice your "else" usage on the post is incorrect
if (document.getElementById('chkMember').checked) {
    var menu= document.getElementById('selProv');
    if(menu.options[menu.selectedIndex].innerText=="Ontario") {
       //your codes goes here
    }else {
           //your change color code here
    }
}

Comment: just wrap your checkbox with div,and change the div color

Comment: This is what I have now: if (document.getElementById('chkMember').checked) {
        var menu = document.getElementById('selProv');
        if (menu.options[menu.selectedIndex].innerText == "Ontario") {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            alert('You must be from Ontario to be a member');
            document.getElementById('chkMember').style.background = "#ff0000";
        }

Comment: @Hendri - While answering, Mention the problem in the code and where what went wrong and how it has to be corrected. Below link will be useful for you.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Yeah i actually just did the div option cause it was easier right before you mention it, thanks again!

Comment: @Hendri - Pease update the answer, it will be helpful for any one in future to understand it clearly by reading your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [Option API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement/Option), the second argument corresponds to the value of that entry. In your `chkIfMember()` function, set `document.getElementById('selProv').value = 9` instead of `document.getElementById('selProv"').value === 'Ontario'`.

Comment: Alert didn't even come up

Comment: You both missed the extra `"` in the ID name.